# Design patterns: exposing notifications using a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, network-programming

I have got several types of a logic controller class that handle the communication with a remote resource. To do so each class uses an instance of a network controller class that deals with the connection details: connects to a resource, sends data, receives data. The logic controller classes are notified of data changes from the network controller class using notifications. So in my current solution **each logic controller class registers for the notifications and implements specific functions to deal with them differently**.

However, if I want to do proper code engineering, I wonder whether it would be **more robust** to use **protocols** and **delegation**.

I wonder if I could define which methods the logical controller classes need to implement in order to receive the notification. However I am not sure if this makes sense and is correct because **I do not want inheritance here**.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Typically you have 1 or 2 (explained later) methods per notification. So it is a quite simple mapping. The reason for that is that you have one notification per "event" and there is little reason to chance that for delegation.

But your design is good. What is the difference between delegation and notifications? (Robustness is not.)

- A **delegate** is a  *single instance* that customizes the behavior of the delegating instance. Therefore beside the usual "inform" methods (`will…`, `did…`) it can have the ability to change the behavior of the delegating, i. e. returning `NO` as an "invalid marker" (`should…`) or change the data set, a operation is executed on. (Sometimes this is the 2nd method for an event.) It is obvious that in such cases you cannot have multiple instances at a time. Delegation is in competition with subclassing and often the better choice (white boxing vs. black boxing).
- You can have as many **notification** receivers as you want to. Obviously they cannot change the behavior of the notification sender. Therefore it is the better choice, if you have several instances that only needs an information that an event happened.

If understood your use case correctly, notifications are perfectly fitting your requirements.